# boost::condition_variable - using wait_for with predicate

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-thread

I would like to wait for a condition for a certain amount of time.
I read the boost documentation and it seems that it is preferable to use the function `wait_for` with a predicate, as described [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref.condition_variable.wait_for_predicate).

Unfortunately the example is not really useful for me. How should I write the predicate? I tried to write the code reported above but the visual studio compiler is complaining: `c:\boost\boost\thread\win32\condition_variable.hpp(394): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments`

This is the part of the code:

```
class MyClass{

  boost::mutex mutex;
  boost::condition_variable myCondition;
  //... 
  void foo();
  bool myPredicate();
}


void MyClass::foo(){

  boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mutex);

  boost::chrono::microseconds period(25000);
  // ...
  boost::chrono::system_clock::time_point wakeUpTime = boost::chrono::system_clock::now() + period;
  if(myCondition.wait_until(lock,wakeUpTime,MyClass::myPredicate) == true){/...}

}

bool MyClass::myPredicate(){

  if(...)
    return true;
  else
    return true;
}
```

What's the correct way of using `wait_for` with predicate?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's recommended to use the `wait` functions with predicate, because they are less error-prone compared to hand-written loops. A hand-written loop might look as follows:

```
for (;;) {
    if (myPredicate()) {
        // ... [successful case]
        break;
    } else if (myCondition.wait_until(lock, wakeUpTime) == boost::cv_status::timeout) {
        // ... [timeout case]
        break;
    } // else: continue loop [spurious wakeup]
}
```

If you pass a predicate to the `wait` function, it might be a function-like thing that can be invoked with no arguments and returns a type, that can be used as a `bool`. For example you can use a `static` member function for that purpose:

```
struct Foobar {
    static bool isFoobar();
};

myCondition.wait_until(lock, wakeUpTime, Foobar::isFoobar);
```

You can't directly pass a non-static member function, because it can only be invoked with an object. However, you can use a function-object instead:

```
struct MyPredicateWrapper {
    MyClass* _ptr;
    explicit MyPredicateWrapper(MyClass* ptr) : _ptr(ptr) { }
    bool operator()() const { return _ptr->myPredicate(); }
};

myCondition.wait_until(lock, wakeUpTime, MyPredicateWrapper(this));
```

You can do basically the same thing with `boost::bind`:

```
myCondition.wait_until(lock, wakeUpTime, boost::bind(&MyClass::myPredicate, this));
```

And if you are using C++11, you can also use a *lambda function*:

```
myCondition.wait_until(lock, wakeUpTime, [this] { return myPredicate(); });
```

Comment: Thanks for this complete anser, so basically using one of the two last proposed methods allows me to invoke the function `myPredicate()` on the current object. Is that correct? This allows me to evaluate the predicate by using variables defined in `myClass`.

Comment: All of them except the first one (`Foobar`) allows you to access instance variables defined in `myClass`. I recommend using the _anonymous function_. It allows you to _inline_ part of the predicate, and bring together what belongs together. However, I am not sure if this feature is already supported by Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes, Visual Studio 2012 supports it, the code compiles. Do you know if is there a way to test it? I mean, predicates are used for avoiding errors in case of spurious weak up. Is there a way to simulate a spurious weak up?