# dead-lock with condition_variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-thread, condition-variable

I'm having a dead-lock when trying to notify a `condition_variable` from a thread.

Here is my MCVE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/condition_variable.hpp>

static boost::mutex m_mutex;
static boost::condition_variable m_cond;

void threadFunc()
{
    std::cout << "LOCKING MUTEX" << std::endl;
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock( m_mutex );
    std::cout << "LOCKED, NOTIFYING CONDITION" << std::endl;
    m_cond.notify_all();
    std::cout << "NOTIFIED" << std::endl;
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    while( true )
    {
        std::cout << "TESTING!!!" << std::endl;

        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock( m_mutex );

        boost::thread thrd( &threadFunc );

        //m_cond.wait( lock );
        while ( !m_cond.timed_wait(lock,boost::posix_time::milliseconds(1)) )
        {
            std::cout << "WAITING..." << std::endl;
        }

        static int pos = 0;
        std::cout << "DONE!!! " << pos++ << std::endl;

        thrd.join();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If using `m_cond.wait( lock );`, I see `DONE!!!` being written for every attempt, no problem here.

If I use the `while ( !m_cond.timed_wait(lock,boost::posix_time::milliseconds(1)) )` loop, I see `DONE!!!` being written for a few attempts, and, at some point, I get a dead lock and waiting finally never ends:

```
TESTING!!!
LOCKING MUTEX
LOCKED, NOTIFYING CONDITION
NOTIFIED
WAITING...
WAITING...
WAITING...
WAITING...
WAITING...
WAITING...
...
```

I have read other posts on stackoverflow (like [Condition variable deadlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912322/condition-variable-deadlock)): they mention that this could happen if `notify_all` is called before condition's wait function is running, so the mutex must be used to prevent that. But I feel like that's what I'm doing:

- I lock the mutex before creating the thread
- Then thread cannot notify before `m_cond.timed_wait` is reached (and then mutex is unlocked)
- Within the loop, in case of timeout, `timed_wait` relocks the mutex so notify cannot be done, we print "WITTING..." and we release the mutex when we are again ready to receive the notification

So why is the dead-lock occuring? Could the condition be notified between the moment when `timed_wait` detects the timeout and relock the mutex?

Comment: I've tried this out with the c++ standard library and it doesn't deadlock: https://compiler-explorer.com/z/Gh7da7

Comment: @JVApen: Clicked your link. It wentto infinite loop after attempt #54!, retried two times, it was OK, on first try, it started WAITING for ever after attempt #284....So this is apparently not a boost issue.

Comment: You don't seem to guard yourself against [spurious wakeups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup).

Comment: ... also, notifying while holding the lock may be a pessimization.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Rainer explains why the mutex needs to be held when notifying the lock here: https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-core-guidelines-be-aware-of-the-traps-of-condition-variables - although in this case it would simply result with an extra ms wait as opposed to waiting forever.

Comment: @Den-Jason In the "_Before I present you this issue, let me at first do it right. Here is the pattern, how to use `condition variables`_" example, he doesn't hold the lock while notifying. I didn't find anything in the text suggesting that it should be done in another way either. There was only a comment to the article expressing some concerns.

Comment: Oh yes - in `setDataReady` he only locks the mutex when updating the shared variable.

Comment: @Den-Jason Yeah, and it's released before notifying.  Keeping it locked while notifying is often seen as a pessimization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that if `timed_wait` completes before `notify_all` is called it will then have to wait for the thread to release the mutex (i.e. after it has called `notify_all`) before it resumes then will call `timed_wait` again, the thread has finished so `timed_wait` will never succeed. There are two scenarios where this can happen, if your thread takes more than a millisecond to start (should be unlikely but the scheduling vagaries of your OS mean it could happen, especially if the CPU is busy) the other is spurious wakeups.

Both scenarios can be guarded against by setting a flag when calling `notify_all` which the waiting thread can check to ensure notify has been called:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/condition_variable.hpp>

static boost::mutex m_mutex;
static boost::condition_variable m_cond;

void threadFunc(bool& notified)
{
    std::cout << "LOCKING MUTEX" << std::endl;
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m_mutex);
    std::cout << "LOCKED, NOTIFYING CONDITION" << std::endl;
    notified = true;
    m_cond.notify_all();
    std::cout << "NOTIFIED" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "TESTING!!!" << std::endl;

        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m_mutex);

        bool notified = false;

        boost::thread thrd(&threadFunc, boost::ref(notified));

        //m_cond.wait( lock );
        std::cout << "WAITING..." << std::endl;
        while (!m_cond.timed_wait(lock, boost::posix_time::milliseconds(1), [&] { return notified; }))
        {
            std::cout << "WAITING..." << std::endl;
        }

        static int pos = 0;
        std::cout << "DONE!!! " << pos++ << std::endl;

        thrd.join();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your code fix the problem. But I'd like to understand. You mean `notify_all` is called while the main is printing "WAITING" within its `while` loop, right? But at this point, the mutex is supposed to be locked as `timed_wait` is supposed to relock it before returning. Do you mean `notify_all` is called between the time when `timed_wait` detected the timeout (here mutex is not locked) and the time it got a chance to relock the mutex?

Comment: All right, I thought `timed_wait` was smart enough to prevent that.

Comment: Shouldn't your `notified` variable be an `atomic_bool`?

Comment: @jpo38 don't think thats necessary, its only being modified by one thread and is already protected by a mutex

Answer (score 0):

A wait on a condition variable has to start before the condition is signalled.  With your code it's possible that a spurious wakeup could allow the thread to complete before the wait begins.

The solution is this - don't wait solely on a condition variable.  Test a shared flag, and use the condition variable to wake up as soon as it is signalled.  See Rainer's guidelines on this here:
https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-core-guidelines-be-aware-of-the-traps-of-condition-variables

Also see this thread about using the boost condition variable with a predicate:
[boost::condition_variable - using wait_for with predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19328858/boostcondition-variable-using-wait-for-with-predicate)

and
[How do I use a boost condition variable to wait for a thread to complete processing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16907072/how-do-i-use-a-boost-condition-variable-to-wait-for-a-thread-to-complete-process)

Comment: "With your code it's possible that the thread would complete before the wait begins". No, it's impossible, the main thread locked the mutex and it's release by the call to `timed_wait`. The worker thread needs the lock to be acquired before it can exit.

Comment: How does that explain that you see "waiting" after "notified" in the log?

Comment: "WAITING..." is printed after `timed_wait`was called, so it could also be "WAITED"...

Comment: So it could be a spurious wakeup as suggested by Ted.